# passing arguments array error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass array argument in c++.
The codes like this.

```
main()
{

...        
double *terms = new double[9];
GuassianTerms(9,1,terms);
```

< terms have not correct values at here>

```
...}


double Cmfc_test5Dlg::Guassian(int x, double sigma)
{
        double c = 2.0 * sigma * sigma;
        return exp(-x * x / c) / sqrt(c * 3.141592f);
}
double Cmfc_test5Dlg::GuassianTerms(int kernalSize, double sigma, double terms[])
{
        terms = new double[kernalSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < kernalSize; ++i) {
                terms[i] = Guassian(i - kernalSize / 2, sigma);
        }
        return 1;//*terms;
}
```

But terms have something wrong values .

How to get a pass arrary argument ?

what should I do for solving for this?

Comment: Why are you doing `terms = new double[kernalSize];` in `GuassianTerms`?

Comment: terms is of type double*, therefore pass it as double * terms. Also, this way will lead to memory leaks, as you have already allocated terms in main. Either dont allocate them again or clean the memory first.

Comment: I'm newbie. so I'don't know where from start to.

Comment: "Does not work well" is not a useful problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double Cmfc_test5Dlg::GuassianTerms(int kernalSize, double sigma, double* terms)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < kernalSize; ++i) {
                terms[i] = Guassian(i - kernalSize / 2, sigma);
        }
        return 1;//*terms;
}
```

Comment: Please add some comments to explain what whas wrong / why do you suggest your answer...

Comment: Thanks I got it;. and I've resolved with your answer. Thanks

Comment: The change from `double[]` to `double*` in the parameter list is mostly cosmetic. The terms are syntactically equivalent, but since it actually is a pointer that is passed, I prefer `double*` as conferring better information to human readers. The change that made a actual difference was removing `terms = new double[kernalSize];` from `GaussianTerms()`. The array had already been allocated in the calling code, and having the statement in the called function leads to confusion and memory leaks, as well as incorrect results.